# Way to edit WindowTitle for use later in bat script?

Tags: batch-file, replace

With the code below i get the window title i wanna use for later.

But it also has "Window Title: " and i also wanna edit out some things.

Is there a way to make it not include "Window Title: " before it becomes a SET variable?

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq wmplayer.exe" /fo list /v ^|find /i "window title" ^|find /v "N/A"') do (SET _WindowMediaPlayerWindowTitle=%%g)
```

Comment: I take it you want to remove "Window Title: " as well? It would help if you provided an example string and get rid of all the unnecessary script code. Is this a case of you not knowing how that script works? Try `help set`.

Comment: Why are you asking for the output in a particular format, then trying to remove the things which are particular to that output?

Comment: As @Compo is pointing out, tasklist provides a neat columnar output, why not just run it through `findstr` in a for loop?

Comment: Been trying to find a way to get the window title without any other info. But this is the only thing i could find when searching online. Is there a way to get the output without "Window Title: "? I'd still want to edit what i get. But it'll be something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 'Window Title' as a variable using your provided method and information:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In (
    'TaskList /V /Fi "ImageName Eq WMPlayer.exe" /Fo List'
) Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%C In ("%%B") Do @Set "_WindowMediaPlayerWindowTitle=%%C"
```

*Once you have the variable you can remove what you want or split it as necessary, but as you've provided no information and it is a separate question, I'll leave that for you to do.*