# Delete specific parts of txt with bat file

Tags: batch-file, text, replace

How do i use a bat file to delete "[", "]", and anything between them.

Plus replace any "." with spaces, and remove everything after the last "."

Then also remove any blank space " " that might be at the start or the end.

Can't seem to find an easy way to do it. Really any way to change these things in a string of text.

Comment: Create a Batch file with this line: `notepad yourFile.txt` and run it. After that, carefully complete all the changes you want. This is the easiest way to do it...

Comment: I want to automate the process in some way. There's gotta be some way. Looking into JREPL thinking i can use that. But seems i have to learn how to use it first.

Comment: Please delete this question and wait for a response to the same problem in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52175545)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to edit WindowTitle for use later in bat script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175545/way-to-edit-windowtitle-for-use-later-in-bat-script)

Comment: @JacobMIX: JREPL is a 2430 lines program! I though you said "an _easy_ way to do it"...

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using JREPL doing something along these lines:

```
jrepl "^\[[^\]]*\]|\.(?!.*\.).*#\." "# " /t # /a|jrepl "^ +| +$" "" /f TextFile.txt /o -
```